# jQuery обработчик нажатия checkbox, которого еще нет

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Есть обработчки нажатия на input checkbox

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(":checkbox").css("box-shadow", "0 0 20px green");
    } else {
        $(":checkbox").css("box-shadow", "0 0 20px red");
    }
});
```

Если на странице уже есть checkbox (в html) , то работает.
Если нет ни одного checkbox до загрузки страницы - не работает.

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы обработчик работал , даже если chеckbox добавляется после загрузки страницы (в jQuery)

Comment: $(':checkbox').on('change', function () { });

Comment: @soledar10 и чем этот код поможет, если элементы создаются **после**  установки обработчика?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov напримет тем, что http://api.jquery.com/on/ **on** слушает динамический контент

Comment: @dluhhbiu Это  если на родителя повесить и указать дополнительный селектор (кстати, спасибо, я этого не знал). А soledar10 предлагает вешать на сами чекбоксы

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Вы правы, не заметил этого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчик нужно навешивать на все, вновь создаваемые, элементы вручную

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var checkClick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(":checkbox").css("box-shadow", "0 0 20px green");
    } else {
      $(":checkbox").css("box-shadow", "0 0 20px red");
    }
  };

  $(":checkbox").change(checkClick);
  
  $(":button").click(function() {
    $(this).before(
      $('<input type="checkbox" />').change(checkClick)
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="button" value="Add">
```

Но, конкретно в Вашем случае, можно обойтись чистым CSS

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(":button").click(function() {
    $(this).before(
      $('<input type="checkbox" />')
    );
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="button" value="Add">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `jQuery` можно повесить обработчик события на блок, в который помещаются ваши `checkbox`, или даже на `body`. Т.е. так:

```
$('body').on('change',':checked', function() {
if (event.target.checked) {
    $(":checkbox").css("box-shadow", "0 0 20px green");
} else {
    $(":checkbox").css("box-shadow", "0 0 20px red");
}
});
```

Но в вашем случае действительно лучше подойдет `css`.

Comment: Кстати с CSS - вопрос. ТС вешает стили на все чекбоксы, а не на кликнутый. Если это не ошибка, то CSS не поможет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да, в таком случае `css` действительно не подойдет, но на самом деле такое действие выглядит весьма сомнительно(вешать стили на все чекбоксы)